# Как лучше отрисовывать элементы на страницы из json c помощью jquery?

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, json

Хочу обновлять строки в таблице из полученного по ajax jsonа. С помощью каких инструментов удобнее всего можно решить такую задачу?

Выглядит это примерно вот так:

```
data = {items: [
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'Element 1', 'qty': 100},
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'Element 2', 'qty': 150},
    {'id': 3, 'name': 'Element 3', 'qty': 200},
    {'id': 4, 'name': 'Element 4', 'qty': 250},   
]}
```

```html
<section class="wrapper">
    <!-- Заголовки -->
    <div class="row">
        <div>Название</div>
        <div>Количество</div>
        <div>Удалить</div>
    </div>

    <!-- Для каждого элемента JSON нужно "на лету" сгенерить такую строку -->
    <div class="row">
        <div>{{name}}</div>
        <div>{{qty}}</div>
        <div class="delete" data-element-id="{{id}}"></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А какие вы хотите здесь инструкменты? цикл по массиву, формирование строки, присоединение к DOM.

На ES2015 так:

```js
data = {items: [
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'Element 1', 'qty': 100},
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'Element 2', 'qty': 150},
    {'id': 3, 'name': 'Element 3', 'qty': 200},
    {'id': 4, 'name': 'Element 4', 'qty': 250},   
]};


data.items.forEach(function(v){
    var row = `<div class="row">
                <div>${v.name}</div>
                <div>${v.qty}</div>
                <div class="delete" data-element-id="${v.id}"></div>
               </div>`;
    $(row).appendTo(".wrapper");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<section class="wrapper">
    <!-- Заголовки -->
    <div class="row">
        <div>Название</div>
        <div>Количество</div>
        <div>Удалить</div>
    </div>
</section>
```

либо можете скрытую строку-шаблон в верстку вставить, потом клонировать ее, заменять значения и добавлять

Comment: В итоге я примерно так и сделал. Но столкнулся с проблемой, что к добавленным элементам нельзя обратиться, по классу или id. Видимо потому что они созданы позже, чем сформировалась DOM. Не знаете как это решить?

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров если под "нельзя обратиться" вы имеете в виду, что не работают обработчики различные, то вешать их надо в виде  `$(".wrapper").on("click", ".delete", function(){ .... })` а не `$(".delete").click(...)`

Comment: идею понял, а как в таком случае получить какое-то значение в функции из .delete, как если бы я использовал $(this), если бы вешал событие клика на .delete?

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров тут ничего не меняется. `$(this)`  будет указывать на кликнутый `.delete`

Comment: Спасибо! Попробую)